# "on the train" or "in the train"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions, in-on

Which of these is correct: "I am on the train" or "I am in the train"?

Answer (score 27):

Both, but they are used differently. Being *on the train* is the most common use.

When you travel by train, you usually say that you are *on the train*.

If you want to describe your position, you could say that you are *in the train*, for example:

> The train has derailed, I have a broken leg. You can find me in the train.

Comment: Here I have a sentence: "Every morning a man gets 'onto/into' the train." Still both proposition are correct or it needs correction here. Please comment. Thanks

Comment: @Kalvaniya: The normal is that a person gets onto a train; that means that he travels by train. Getting into a train suggests that he enters the train for some other reason as the usual form is avoided.

Answer (score 11):

Being *on the train* has the sense of being *aboard* or being *a passenger on* a conveyance.

Being *in the train* has the sense of being a component member of the train. Keep in mind that the word *train* refers to more than just railroads, and that a railroad train is something that comprises a group of connected cars and locomotive engines. It is proper to say that the car you are riding in is *in the train*. You would be *in the train* if you were part of a walking tour group or pilgrimage -- or even caught up in a conga line.

Answer (score 5):

To answer this question, I cannot offer a better explanation than you will find in this George Carlin monologue: [On airlines and flying](https://youtu.be/vdPy5Ikn7dw?t=3m5s).

You'll want to listen to the whole thing, but the part that addresses your question begins at 2:55 in the video.

Essentially, Carlin is making fun of the seemingly arbitrary prepositions English uses. We say "get **on** the airplane" when what you're actually doing is getting **in** the airplane.

Carlin also pokes fun at the idea of an "almost" collision between two aircraft being called a "near miss": "It's a near hit, gang!" he points out.

Comment: Scrolled down to see if anyone had referenced Carlin. +1 :-D Link rot again though, try this link: https://youtu.be/vdPy5Ikn7dw?t=3m5s

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors: Thanks. I replaced the rotten one with yours.

Answer (score 3):

I am in the train right now.   (I'm not outside the train.)

I am on the train right now.   (Could be I'm travelling on the train.)

Hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're on because you got on.  Like you're in the shower, bath or car because you got in.  Unless you're on the roof of the car.

If you are on the roof of the train, you're on [the] top of the train.  When you're on the train, you can go in the buffet car, when you do, you'll be in the buffet car of the train.

You also get off the train, but get out of your car, bath or shower.  Probably because you got on, possibly because it is short for getting on board.

The word train, is from the French verb traîner, to pull.  So it's called a train because it's being pulled, that might explain why you need to be on the train (to be pulled), rather than in it (to be pulling).

Answer (score 0):

I'm *on* the train, but I'm *in* carriage D. Don't ask my why; there's often no rhyme or reason to English prepositions.

Comment: You are *in* carriage D, and carriage D is *in* the train. The train is the group of cars, etc., that forms a line. You are not a part of the line, so you cannot be *in the train*; you are merely riding in one of the cars that *is* part of the line.

Comment: That *appears* to make it more logical. However, I've got off the train and now I'm *on* the bus.

Comment: Old usage -- omnibus carriages (the current version is just a motorized version of something that has been around for centuries) have not always been enclosed (and some still are not). Keep throwing -- I'll keep catching :o).

Comment: There's probably no rhyme or reason to prepositions in most languages: they're shifty creatures.  Russians work ON a factory, Spanish people lie IN a beach and the French use 'de' or 'a' for nearly everything.